# How to apply this mutt sidebar patch?

Tags: macos, git, patch, mutt

Since the homebrew guys now have removed the option of appying the mutt sidebar patch during installation i went searching and found someone who had created an updated mutt sidebar patch for version 1.5.22 of mutt (every mutt sidebar versions seems to always be incompatible with the previous or the next).

The patch however, which is just a .patch file on a github repository, located here https://github.com/nedos/mutt-sidebar-patch doesnt contain any installation instructons. Since the homebrew package is a binary package im not sure how to install this since you usually need to point the patch command at a file you want to patch.

After some more searching i found out how someone had used a patch they found on git to patch some other software, they had cloned the git repository and used the git command to apply the patch, but then again im dont know the github repository url (if git is being used) for the 1.5.22 version of mutt, and im also not sure if i would have to recompile it.

Can someone point me in the right direction and give me some hints? Preferably a solution.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This answer has become a bit out of date. Thankfully some people have created some homebrew taps to solve this problem for us and make it much simpler. All you have to do now is the following:

```
brew uninstall mutt
brew tap sgeb/mutt
brew install sgeb/mutt/mutt --with-sidebar-patch
```

If you want to install mutt with some other patches, have a look to see what you can install with this tap, by typing:

```
brew options sgeb/mutt/mutt
```

The output for me was:

```
--with-confirm-attachment-patch
    Apply confirm attachment patch
--with-debug
    Build with debug option enabled
--with-forwref-patch
    Apply forward_references patch
--with-gettext
    Build with gettext support
--with-gmail-labels-patch
    Apply gmail labels patch
--with-gmail-server-search-patch
    Apply gmail server search patch
--with-gpgme
    Build with gpgme support
--with-ignore-thread-patch
    Apply ignore-thread patch
--with-libidn
    Build with libidn support
--with-pgp-verbose-mime-patch
    Apply PGP verbose mime patch
--with-s-lang
    Build against slang instead of ncurses
--with-sidebar-patch
    Apply sidebar patch
--with-trash-patch
    Apply trash folder patch
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

---

I had problems following all of the answers above. I did actually manage to get it to work in the end. What I did was the following

```
brew edit mutt
```

then I scrolled down to a section of commands that all start with "option", sort of like:

```
option "with-debug", "Build with debug option enabled"
option "with-trash-patch", "Apply trash folder patch"
option "with-s-lang", "Build against slang instead of ncurses"
option "with-ignore-thread-patch", "Apply ignore-thread patch"
option "with-pgp-verbose-mime-patch", "Apply PGP verbose mime patch"
option "with-confirm-attachment-patch", "Apply confirm attachment patch"
```

I then added a line at the bottom of this block

```
option "with-sidebar-patch", "Apply sidebar patch"
```

After that I scrolled down further to the section with all the patches, e.g.

```
patch do
  url "http://patch-tracker.debian.org/patch/series/dl/mutt/1.5.21-6.2+deb7u1/features/trash-folder"
  sha1 "6c8ce66021d89a063e67975a3730215c20cf2859"
end if build.with? "trash-patch"
```

And I added the patch for sidebar (as I found here: https://github.com/kevwil/homebrew-patches/blob/master/mutt.rb)

```
patch do
  url "https://raw.github.com/nedos/mutt-sidebar-patch/7ba0d8db829fe54c4940a7471ac2ebc2283ecb15/mutt-sidebar.patch"
  sha1 "1e151d4ff3ce83d635cf794acf0c781e1b748ff1"
end if build.with? "sidebar-patch"
```

Finally, exit the editor for the brew file and in the commandline:

```
brew install mutt --with-sidebar-patch
```

Best of luck!

p.s. if it gives you an error of the form `aclocal` then you need to install automake, `brew install automake`

Comment: When I do `brew install mutt --with-sidebar-patch` , It says `Warning: mutt-1.5.23_2 already installed`

Comment: @Hebbian You have to do `brew remove mutt` before installing it again with the sidebar patch.

Comment: For mutt 1.5.23_2, this patch worked for me:
`url "http://lunar-linux.org/~tchan/mutt/patch-1.5.23.sidebar.20140412.txt"
sha256 "5f473e201519d95b8c2319f286221213386de2d7c27629c70733b40b643b59c4"`

Comment: FYI, the sidebar patch on that git repo is a bit old and doesn't include the sidebar_format capability. I used this link (http://lunar-linux.org/~tchan/mutt/patch-1.5.23.sidebar.20140412.txt) from the new maintainer (don't forget to change the sha1 hash) and it has the latest sidebar features.

Comment: I think the command has to be `brew reinstall mutt`, rather than `install`

Answer (score 4):

This tap includes the patch and seems to have kept up to date well.

https://github.com/kevwil/homebrew-patches

Comment: This does seem easier than the accepted answer `brew reinstall kevwil/patches/mutt`

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the homebrew formula: brew edit mutt
2. Add the sidebar patch according to these instructions: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.mutt.user/41752
3. Brew mutt again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this tap has the patch, and it seems to work well for me. The README has pretty detailed instructions on how to install.

https://github.com/sgeb/homebrew-mutt

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself now by downloading the source, adding the patch with the patch command, then ran configure with the the functionality i needed in mutt, then added a configuration directive for displaying the side bar..and when opening mutt the sidebar is now present but it doenst list any folders yet, i suspect this just to be a matter of additional configuration thats needed though